# require builder returning false in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-3-upgrade

I am upgrading my rails application from rails 2.3 to rails 3.1. I am using builder like this

```
b = Builder::XmlMarkup.new :target => @data, :indent => 2
```

this works in `rails 2.3` but not in `3.1`.

Also, when i try to execute `require 'builder'` from rails console it works in `rails 2.3` but says **false** in `rails 3.1`

Also, when i try to execute `xm = Builder::XmlMarkup.new` on console it prints `<inspect>`.

Also, when i do bundle show in rails 2.3 i see that builder is of version **`3.2.2`** but when i am checking the same in rails 3.1 builder is **`3.0.4`**.

Can anyone help. Thanks.